# Linking separate C programs together

Tags: c, project

I'm need some help on a project, the plan is to make a C program that can take an input file name and then do these three tasks:

1. copy it's contents and store it's duplicate in another user specified location
2. change the backup file's format, i.e from ".txt" to something like ".img"
3. encrypt the contents of the file (any cypher method)

Note: the input file name has to be scanned during execution

I and my team have already made about 75% of it but it's in separate parts like each of the following three tasks is an individual program, 
and we are having trouble combining them.

Another error is that we are using "rename" function from files concept to copy files and change their format and we don't have any idea of how to use `scanf` to read the file name and give it as input to the rename function.

So if you could give me any suggestions..I'd really be grateful.

Comment: What do you expect us to tell you? You can't just take the totally separate work of multiple people that do independent tasks totally on their own and throw them together. You and your team should have been working together from the start to design and create integrated code. Now you're going to have to work together to rewrite everything to create that integration after the fact. There's no *magic wand* that you can wave and make all that code suddenly combine and work.

Comment: `made about 75%` `don't have any idea of how to use scanf to read the file name and give it as input to the rename function`. You didn't finish step 2 or 1, which takes you below 75% of the work. The 3 steps you take are... well... trivial. It is even easier to write using bash commands and openssl. If you have 3 separate programs, copy the essential parts from them and create one program from it. That is what programmers essentialy do (and are paid for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a little while since I've used it, but you could consider using make and creating a makefile.  According to what I have seen from the references I've looked up, a basic makefile looks kind of like this.

makefile.h:

```
basicMakefile: basicMake1.c, basicMake2.c, basicMake3.c
      gcc -o basicMakefile basicMake1.c basicMake2.c basicMake3.c -I
```

As for using scanf, suppose we have

```
char str1[20]; //creates a char array(a string) that is 20 chars long

printf("Enter the new name for the file: ");
scanf("%s" , str1); //puts the user entered value into str1
```

you could then do

```
rename(str1) //function call with the new filename
//whatever your rename funtion does for the logic
```

Below are the references that I used, I would strongly recommend taking a more in-depth look at these as they explain these concepts in more detail than what I could fit in here.  My above examples are derived from the ones found in them.

Make Documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Scanf Tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Simple Makefile Tutorial: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/